# Is there a java ide that is a .jar itself?

Tags: java, ide, executable-jar

Is there a java ide that is a .jar itself? I need an IDE for school and exe's are blocked but jar's are not.

Comment: If there is it sucks.

Comment: You seriously can't install and IDE on your school's machines?

Comment: Why not install eclipse portable onto a usb stick and use that?

Comment: Yup, I.T. technicians are practically dictators.

Comment: [You can run eclipse without using exe files](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134738/java-ide-written-in-pure-java). It will probably still load some dlls though.

Comment: How do they expect you to work if they don't give you the tools you need?

Comment: I do not understand the down votes.

Comment: @Vash Agreed.  Some people just like to ride the hate train.

Comment: [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org) is at least a programmer's editor in java. It may work out of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should discuss this with your teacher.

- If the teacher is aware of the problem, he / she may have a pedagogical reason for not wanting you use an IDE.  (An IDE is *not* essential for Java programming, and you could argue that you learn the language more deeply if you don't have an IDE completing things and suggesting corrections.)
- If the teacher is not aware of the problem, he / she may be able to solve it for you ... and other students in your class ... by arranging that an IDE is available for *all* students to use.

Answer (score 2):

[BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) is an IDE designed to help teach the Java language.  It is available as an executable JAR which can be [downloaded](http://www.bluej.org/download/download.html) from the website.

Answer (score 1):

I can not came up with anything like that. But you should ask your teacher to install preferred IDE on school machine. You should keep in mind that, you should used what is on that PC if a IDE is not part of software you can used. Then you should used notepad and javac.

beside that an IDE is not required for basic projects. Using simple editor you will for sure make bigger progress as you will have to understand the basics that are crucial in every matter.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Dr Java is a standalone jar file. It's pretty good for small stuff, however if you have a big project (many classes, packages, etc), I'd figure out a way to get Eclipse running.

http://drjava.org/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here:

http://tgducusin.blogspot.com/2011/12/portable-eclipse-with-java-jdk-tomcat.html

It's not a jar, but it should work for you, unless of course you literally meant **all** exe's are blocked (since even in the portable version, you still need to use the exe file to run it).  I'm hoping you only meant exe *installers* are blocked.

Ignore the parts about Tomcat and PostgreSQL if you don't need them.